# How to get an urgent answer if your local rabbi isn't reachable

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, how-to, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

I think many frum people have been in the situation of needing time-sensitive help with a halachic question, but not having access to their/any rabbi. What resources such as hotlines are available to such people for getting halachic information from a Torah expert fast?

*I am not talking about formal piskei or even formal teshuvos (the distinction between "psak" and "information" is discussed somewhat [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77732/if-you-get-a-psak-then-hear-that-it-is-wrong-what-must-you-do/77786#77786)). Discussions about the halachic appropriateness of using a hotline for Torah information on an occasional basis--even a different community's hotline--or of whether you should go to a hotline rather than to, say, a published halacha summary, a primary source, or a local rabbi from a different shita--are not on the epistemic level of my question; about that, CYLOR, if you can ;)*

*This question is subtly different from [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/consulting-a-local-orthodox-rabbi-if-there-isnt-one) one, because here I am talking about isolated, occasional incidents.*

Also related:

[Reliable Ask-a-Rabbi Websites](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/reliable-ask-a-rabbi-websites)

[How do I find answers to sensitive questions I can't ask my rabbi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34566/how-do-i-find-answers-to-sensitive-questions-i-cant-ask-my-rabbi)

Comment: You don’t ask it on here, for starters. :)

Answer (score 10):

The best option is probably the Beis Din of your own community; see if they are reachable by phone; they may well be. That said, someone I sort of know has experience with the following hotlines in the States.

(I am not in a position to judge their halachic permissibility or reliability. It seems that you should tell the rabbi on the hotline whose minhag and opinions you usually follow, though perhaps they will ask, if it is necessary to know.)

**845-HALACHA** -- Monsey, I think. It's either 24/7 or 24/6, and I believe it lets you choose language, as well as whether you want a litvish or chassidish or sefardic or maybe other type of dayan.

**516-239-2500 / 718-337-8370** -- The Halacha Hotline of the Five Towns and Far Rockaway Community under the leadership of Rabbi Binyomin Forst. One of the numbers may be a pay-per-minute number, but they will quickly tell you how to call them for free if you express a need. Seemingly not available Shabbos or Yom Tov.

**718-604-8000** -- The Beis Din of Crown Heights. Chabad. At least one dayan is usually available during business hours. Some phone numbers for other hours are listed [here](http://www.chcentral.org/resources/rabbonim/). (I suggest you pay [mas hakohol](http://www.chcentral.org/payment-site/) if you are from the community and/or you are using them a lot.)

--

Others I found on Google and know little about:

**(732) 363-1616 / (908) 670-1596 / 732.905.9992** - Bais Horaah of Lakewood. 24 hours. Paid; for details see [here](http://baishoraah.org/callcenter/about/).

**1.844.200.TSHC (8742) / call or text 732.9300.SHC (742) / 732.276.2173**  -- The Sephardic Halacha Center/Rabbi Ariel Ovadia. Details [here](https://theshc.org/contact/).

**877-845-8455** -- For questions about business halacha.

**1- 877-963-8938** and international numbers [here](http://www.yoatzot.org/hotline/) -- Women's health questions. Limited hours; see link.

**855-482-4272** -- Tahareinu (confidential taharas hamishpacha hotline). Israel, Canada, UK, Belgium numbers [here](http://www.torathamishpacha.com/48783.html).

**718-951-3696** -- Shmiras Haloshon questions. From 9:00 to 10:30 p.m. (east coast time) Monday thru Thursday and Saturday nights.

**410-484-4110 x238.** -- Star-K kosher hotline, under the guidance of HaRav Mordechai Frankel; you may have to leave a message.

--

International numbers,in addition to those above:

**Israel KAV HALACHA HOTLINE 02-569-5103** Halacha Shailos Hotline for the English speaking community -24 Hours a day (From 2am until 5:30am only urgent shailos). Momenus (Choshen Mishpat/Ribbis) 2-3pm and 9-11pm at Ext. 3. Sephardi Line, Sun-Tues 8:30-11pm and Fri 1pm until Shabbat at Ext 2. For the complete schedule or to donate, email KavHalacha@gmail.com

**416-785-7902 or Rabbi Chanoch Ehrentreu at 416-712-9752**-- Kollel Toronto, Canada. The first number is available M-F from 9:30 to 10:30 Toronto time; the second is for time-sensitive questions at other times. May also be reachable in the US.

**0825 660 660 (France), 0747 268 268 (Israel), 022 519 0555 (Switzerland), 514 446 9111 (Canada)** -- French-language hotlines, more information [here](http://allorav.com/)

Comment: Its good to always remember that a psak asked for, need only be followed maximally for the current occasion. (that pot of cholent, that shabbos) The questioner may go learn the Halachah on their own (and come to a different conclusion) or ask a different Rabbi they are used to,  and adhere to the new psak or information on the next occasion going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this question will be removed ultimately. But each of these links has telephone hotlines listed.

Bais Horaah is out of Lakewood, NJ and appears to handle any halachic question that is pressing.

The Star-K and OU links have telephone hotlines for kashrut questions.

And Chayim Aruchim, which is affiliated with Agudat Yisroel of America has a telephone hot line for medical questions.

I'm not sure if Ask Moses is what you had in mind. I'm not sure it is staffed by qualified Rabbis or not. But they do have a 24/6 live chat and you can ask for specific "Scholars" which includes some Rabbis.

http://baishoraah.org/callcenter/

http://www.star-k.org/ask-rabbi

https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/03/2013/got_a_kashrut_question_a_s_k_t_h_e_ou_kosher_consumer_hotline/

http://www.chayimaruchim.com/contact.asp?pagetype=Rabbi

http://www.askmoses.com/en/about.html